# How do I install Maxthon 3?

Tags: browser

I've been trying to find a way to install Maxthon 3 on Ubuntu but it's not working and it doesn't work in Wine ever so.

Help or suggestion on the topic that helps me run Maxthon good will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Roland. It seems that Maxthon 3 for Ubuntu is a no go, even through Wine.

There's a few reports that Maxthon 2 does work in Ubuntu via Wine. If you're interested, I have given you the instructions for it:

**Step 1 - Install Wine 0.9.61 or above**

Wine is an environment for running Windows applications in Linux. Please search the Internet for detailed installation instruction.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Note: If you haven't installed any compression/uncompression utilities, a few have to be installed to proceed. Run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract rar unrar
```

**Step 2 - Install IEs4Linux**

IEs4Linux enables the use of various versions of IE in Linux. In this case IE6 version is installed though IE7 version is already available. Please check IEs4Linux's help for detailed installation instruction.

```
wget http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/downloads/ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
cd ies4linux-*
./ies4linux
```

**Step 3 - Install Maxthon**

To install Maxthon, start IE and open Maxthon's installer (Maxthon.exe) from IE's File menu ("File > Open..."). Alternatively put Maxthon's installer to the folder `~/.ies4linux/ie6/drive_c/` and run the commands below:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/<your main folder>/.ies4linux/ie6" 
wine "c:\Maxthon.exe"
```

**Step 4 - Install Additional Libraries**

Start Maxthon by the running the commands below:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/<your main folder>/.ies4linux/ie6"
wine "c:\Maxthon2\Maxthon.exe"
```

There will be a few error messages about missing libraries, including mfc42.dll, msvcp60dll, and a few others. Copy these dlls from Windows (mostly in the System32 folder) to Ubuntu's `~/.ies4linux/ie6/drive_c/windows/system32` folder.

**Step 5 - Setting Program Compatibility**

By Default Wine sets compatibility mode to Windows 98 for all Windows programs. While Maxthon 2's ansi version supports Windows 98, it is the unicode version actually installed in this case. So Wine is configured to run Maxthon Windows XP compatibility mode:

- open Wine's configuration window
- add "Maxthon.exe" and set compatibility to Windows XP
- in the "Drive" tab, map "C:\" to `/home/<your main folder>/.ies4linux/ie6/drive_c`

Answer (score 0):

Maxthon 3 doesn't really work too well with Wine as far as I know.

Your best bet would be to install it, and then run it from a terminal using `wine /path/to/maxthon.exe`, and then see if any .dlls are missing, and add these from a legitimate Windows install.

I often use dllfiles (the website) for missing dlls (but this is really not recommended).

You can use `winetricks` (install it from the software center) to install the dlls it supports.